# Unity launcher,top panel,Dash and title bar disappeared

Tags: launcher, panel

I have installed UBUNTU 13.04 32bit,afer installing CCSM and NVIDIA drive,Unity launcher,top panel,Dash and title bar disappeared.
Now what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I should perhaps be saying this in a comment, but I don't have enough points.

That happened to me one time, and I think it was because I uninstalled COMPIZ. Did you do it as well?

Answer (score 0):

It’s a problem with graphics driver. You may need to remove the NVIDIA driver.

You may know that you can open a Terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and remove the recently installed packages with `sudo apt-get remove packages` and replace *packages* with package name(s). If you don’t know the name of packages, you can find them in Software Center history – you can open Software Center by `software-center` through terminal.

(Maybe this is a way to undo the problematic changes rather than a solution.)